# Image in <div img>

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, image

Not working with my images that are inside a folder 'images'.

`<img src....>` in the div won't help me.
I need to do it inside the div `<div style=..[here]> ..` because it's not something default.

Thank you.

EDIT: After using this:

```
style="background-image: url('/wwwroot/images/Chinchilla.jpg')"
```

it's error me while I open the console (f12) .

```
'Chinchilla.jpg:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)'
```

Why thats? it's local at wwwroot/images/..

Comment: If you need to fill a div, it's still usually better to use an img element and then style the element to fill the div.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to set an image source from the style property is to set it as a background image. The syntax for that is:
`<div style="background-image: url('/folder/path/image2.jpg');">`

Note that background image and img styling are very different.

It seems like what you're saying though is you need to set an image dynamically. If so, you're going to have to use a little javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myImage").src = "image2.jpg";
</script>
```

or if you really do want to set a background image:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.getElementById("myImage").style.backgroundImage = "url('image2.jpg')";
</script>
```

Comment: Well it's not working, I am trying to do this: (with out my parmatrs atm, and with out any code only HTML, and it's not working.
<div>
    <div style="background-image: url('/wwwroot/images/Dolphin.jpg');">
        <h5>example</h5>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li>Pet Age: <strong>00</strong> </li>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
        <button class="btn-primary">Details</button>
    </div>
</div>

Comment: As noted, the styles are different than that of an image attribute. A background image has its own properties. Try:
 
<div style="background-image: url('/wwwroot/images/Dolphin.jpg');background-size: 100%;">

Comment: Also as stated, if that image is dynamic (not stored in your local files) as you mentioned before, it's not going to render. Images render asynchronously AFTER the dom as already been rendered. Test this out with a local image first. Better yet, I would take an hour and read through w3schools HTML documentation (https://www.w3schools.com/html/default.asp). Reading docs always saves time in the long run. Other than that, you're own your own. Maybe if you shared a git pull we could help ya better?

Comment: I've another problem now, I've edited the post.

Comment: A 404 error means the file (on a server) doesn't exist. This confirms my suspicion that it is indeed a dynamic file. I think you may be in over your head on this. No offense meant here, just friendly advice... I think you need to learn quite a bit more about the fundamentals. Programming is a long and windy road. Especially when you're working w frameworks. ASP.net is more advanced stuff. Maybe move your questions to an ASP thread?

Comment: Hello David, thanks for the advice but as you see I am trying to learn here, I've been searching W3SChool, google, and everything you want about this problem, belive me , if you can help me I will be very thankful, Those pictures are exists under WWWROOT, and the path is 100% right.